# Binding a script to dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, placeholder, polyfills, shim

I need to support the placeholder attribute back to IE8. I have traditionally found this script to be excellent for doing this:

https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim/blob/master/jquery.html5-placeholder-shim.js

However it does not bind to dynamically created elements. So if a new input is added to the page with JS the placeholder will not work.

Is there a way to apply this script to the dynamically created elements?

Answer (score 1):

Basically ..No.

As with most plugins (that aren't strictly event based) you need to initialize the plugin for the new elements after they are created.

In modern browsers you could use things like MutationObservers but the reason you need this plugin is to support old browser so that concept won't work

Answer (score 1):

Does calling `jQuery.placeholder.shim();` work? This is the method that's called on ready/load so might do the trick.

If it doesn't then you probably can't at least not directly using that particular plugin in its current form. You could possibly alter the source to handle it.

Are they dynamically generated on page load? Could you simply defer loading of the plugin until after these elements are generated?

The only other long shot I've got is could you wrap the plugin in a function and recall it after each input is generated? This could have unintended side effects but might be a cheap and nasty alternative.

Comment: Yep looking at the source further the shim method looks like the best bet. It prepares a config object which is then passed to $.fn._placeholder_shim which in turn does all the heavy lifting. You might be able to pass the shim() method a config object specifying a selector to target only the new elements ie jQuery.placeholder.shim({selector : 'input#newElement1'});

Comment: nothing nasty about the last idea...it's been done that way for years. Easy to add a class to the ones that have already been set up and filter them out using not()

Comment: Nah I meant calling the entire plugin again repeatedly as opposed to just the method that instantiates a placeholder. If it iterates over every input on the page and doesn't take a selector then you'd end up with things like duplicate event handlers and other mess, apply it to dynamically generating a large quantity of inputs then you can quickly end up with performance issues. At the point I wrote that I hadn't noticed the "shim" method only the jQuery.fn._placeholder_shim method which doesn't work if you call it via $('selector')._placeholder-shim() as it requires a config object.

Comment: Agreed the selectors are the important part, but I don't think any of the methods exposed by the shim take a selector in the traditional jQuery style it instead uses config.selector as a selector. Calling the entire plugin repeatedly doesn't look as nasty as I thought it might be - the shim() method only will be called once but this also probably means that loading the entire plugin again won't apply it to dynamically generated elements